# std::transform a custom tree into a new tree

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, c++14

I have a tree like datastructure defined as:

```
template<typename T>
struct node {
  T val;
  node<T>* parent;
  unique_ptr<node<T>> next_sibling;
  unique_ptr<node<T>> first_child;
};

template<typename T>
struct tree {
    ...
  private:
    unique_ptr<node<T> _head;
};
```

I have also defined several iterators for the tree class (preorder, inorder...).

Using `std::transform` on the given tree works:

```
tree<int> t;
...
std::transform(t.begin(), t.end(), t.begin(), [](){});
```

However I know want to have something analogous to a `back_inserter` to build up a new tree with the same hierarchy:

```
tree<int> t_n;
std::transform(t.begin(), t.end(), my_inserter(t_n));
```

How can this be done?

Comment: But it's not really a regular `back_inserter` since it is not a linear structure -- a tree has branches. I think it will be hard to do this with `std::transform`.

Comment: I am aware that ``back_inserter`` is linear - this exactly the problem I am struggling with :).

Comment: So *why* do you feel you *must* use `std::transform`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it all depends on whether you can define the `back_inserter`.

And it can be done, but **not** with `value_type = T`. The problem is that a plain sequence does not contain enough information to reconstruct the shape of the tree (except in special cases like binary heaps).

So you'll have to iterate over different value type that composes the node value and some information about the shape of the tree. I see two options:

- use a nullable wrapper around T (`boost::option<T>`) and serialize both next_sybling and first_child after each node, as none if not present, or
- use an additional flag specifying whether the node has children and whether it has more siblings, something like `std::tuple<T, bool, bool>`.

And then you should be able to reconstruct the tree in the inserter, using pre-order iteration, preferably depth-first, but breadth-first would work too. Either way, you'll have to keep the same state of iteration in the inserter as you do in the reading iterator, so it will be quite a bit of code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Could you please explain these two points in a bit more detail - unfortunately I can't really see how all of this should come together. Do you mean replacing the ``value_type`` in ``tree_node``?

Comment: @j.dog, no, in the iterator. When you dereference the iterator, you get something. Normally it is some kind of reference to `T`. But in this case you need some extra info there to be able to reconstruct the tree. And I call it `value_type`, because it is the value of `std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type` (which defaults to `typename I::value_type`) where `I` is the iterator in use.

Comment: I could also try to make the iterator return a ``node`` and overload the implicit conversion operator that converts the node to the value?

Comment: @j.dog, you can make the iterator return a node if you want. But you can't do implicit conversion, because the insert operator also needs the tree shape info, which means the information has to pass through the transform function.